# Label on the substance bag in the tv show maniac

Tags: meaning, katakana

In S01E03 of maniac we can see this bag:

[image]

What is the symbol between テ and ー ?
Is it supposed to be 1, like for version 1? If so shouldn't it go after the ー?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a number 1, as you might think. It is a valid katakana which is a small イ: ィ.

The word in question is then:

> アフロダイティー

These kind of small kana are used in conjunction with the previous kana in order to modify the sound. In this case, where the kana is テ and gives a 'te' sound, adding the small kana ィ in front to make ティ gives the 'ti' sound that normally can't be expressed in the standard kana range. Recall that the normal sound for the 'i' range in the た row gives us ち or チ 'chi'.

So, now that you know this, what word is this?

Comment: Well, It should mean Aphrodite (the goddess)  - although I can't find the exact spelling on the Japanese wiki for Aphrodite - (https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC)

Comment: @coconut It could be an alternative spelling of Aphrodite after the English pronunciation for the word, but it's true that the standard spelling and pronunciation for this word in Japanese is アプロディーテー, after the Greek Ἀφροδίτη. Keep in mind that both of these are approximations, at best, and either one of these as well as any of the suggested alternatives listed on the wiki page are acceptable but may not be universally understood.

Answer (score 5):

アフロダイティー

It is a small イ.

It is called sutegana. 
https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2017/12/small-kana.html
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sutegana
[https://jlearn.net/Dictionary/Browse/2072880-sutegana-すてがな-捨て仮名](https://jlearn.net/Dictionary/Browse/2072880-sutegana-%E3%81%99%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA-%E6%8D%A8%E3%81%A6%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/118915/meaning/m0u/捨仮名/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/118915/meaning/m0u/%E6%8D%A8%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D/)
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/捨て仮名](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8D%A8%E3%81%A6%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D)